# Import HTML As String With PHP Vars

Tags: php

I've got an ajax call returning some html.  The html is created and returned in a function like so:

```
function return_html(){
    $title = 'My Form';
    $returnObject = array();
    $returnObject['html'] = '
                <form>
                    <h1>' . $title . '</h1>
                    <input type="text" name="title"/>
                </form>
    ';

    return json_encode($returnObject);
}
```

What I'd like to do is write a .php file with all of my html and vars in it like this...

```
<form>
    <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
</form>
```

and then in my function import that file as a string with the vars set sorta like this:

```
function return_html(){
    $title = 'My Form';
    $returnObject = array();
    $returnObject['html'] = my_file_as_string_but_with_vars_replaced('formFile.php');   
    return json_encode($returnObject);
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds you like you want to build a templating engine.

Comment: @hamish, something similar, although on a very small scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
function return_html() {
    $title = 'My Form';

    ob_start();
    require 'formFile.php';
    $returnObject = array('html' => ob_get_clean());

    return json_encode($returnObject);
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna ask before I try... will this replace my php vars with their values?  I'm not 100% certain, but I imagine I'll get my php statements as a string... eg instead of replacing the 'echo $title' I'll actually see 'echo $title' in the output.

Comment: The variables will be replaced in the required file. In fact, all this is doing is evaluating the required file and capturing the output as a string. I've tested this on my personal web server, and it should work with php5.